# mysql query for every next element following a pattern

Tags: mysql

I have a table with events that are logged into a table, there can be many events like 'start', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', .. and so on

I want to find all **first** entries that have the event 'a' **and** that are following a  'start' event.

The a everty after start is usualy the a event i am searching for, but not always.

So what i got is to tage the next event by auto id, but not by logic, this is 90% right, but not always:

```
SELECT b. *
FROM log AS a
LEFT JOIN log AS b ON a.id = b.id -1
WHERE a.event = 'start'
```

Is there a pure mysql way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not very optimized or performant I guess but it would work

```
SELECT a.*
FROM log AS a
WHERE a.event = 'a' && "start" = (SELECT event FROM log WHERE id<a.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: this is much better, but on lots of querys really a bit slow. Just for info, i solved it inside a script (get all, foreach, set flag on first finding, fetch on flag & wanted object)